# Can Firebase hosting restrict access to resources?

Tags: firebase-hosting

Is it possible to restrict access to a resource (i.e. index.html) depending on whether the user is logged in or not? Maybe something like .htaccess?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Firebase hosting doesn't implement access control to static resources.

Also see the discussion in the comments of this question: [Firebase route security without AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368076/firebase-route-security-without-angularfire)

Comment: Hi Frank, as said in the comments of our mentioned question, I have a confidentiality contract over the project, so I can´t have the CDN files (FrBs-Host) publicly available before project's release, and my clients live in other cities so we do advancement checks over Internet. Could you recommend some way around for using the actual FrBs-Host without letting the CDN to be publicly available rather than using another hosting?

Answer (score 11):

There's new info on this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions
(example:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint )

You should be able to use a Cloud Function to restrict access to content (which is server-side authenticated and generated).

Comment: Cloud functions are US hosting only, not usable for rest of the World

Comment: Cloud functions are meanwhile not only hosted in the US. For Firebase you can choose between regions in the US, Europa and Asia: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

Comment: meanwhile "Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only" as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions