# how to control login session with firebase in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want only register user can view my app but I don't know how can I do it using firebase in ReactJS.

when I type localhost:3000/home
it is visible without loggedin

Comment: Check whether the user is logged in (in a script on that page), if they aren't you can redirect them.

Comment: [Firebase Hosting does not have a built-in way to control who can access the resources](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27212004). But you can use security rules to control who can access what data in the [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) or [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/).