# Firebase Hosting deploy only for auth users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Is it somehow possible to deploy my app using firebase hosting, and there use a an under construction template and a login email and password.

Once user sign's in and the email is known email as admin for example, let them see the entire public directory otherwise if the email is not an admin email set in database for example then just show them a message that we will email them once site is public.

How can I do something like this ?

Comment: It is possible, but this is a long task I think you need to start something. And when you need a short task (something like login page, btw check firebaseui at  Github) than ask your question again with snipped code.

Comment: There is no way to prevent specific users from accessing files on Firebase Hosting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your reply!