# Is there a way in which I can protect my files in a folder by stating it is not a firebase user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Hello Is there a way in which I can apply a function to all the pages in a folder.

For example, if I have a user folder that has all the pages that a firebase User has access too how do I restrict access to that folder for everyone that is not a user with a

```
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
            // maintain the page
            } else {
                window.location = 'index.html'
            }
        });
```

thank you

Comment: There is currently no way to limit who can access files in Firebase Hosting. All files are publicly accessible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you i will look at the duplicated question