# How do you protect images from hotlinking if they are hosted with firebase?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I want to protect images from being hotlinked on my firebase hosted site. Keep in mind these images are not located in the storage area of firebase where I know rules can be deployed. Is there a way to disable hotlinking in the header config or elsewhere?

I have consulted the [hosting docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config), but I am not sure what I am trying to achieve is possible.

Comment: Download URLs are public and non-guessable. There are no access controls on them beyond that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok. Thanks.

Comment: I now see that you actually asked about files on hosting. My reference to download URLs was related to Cloud Storage for Firebase. There are definitely no access controls on Firebase Hosting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources