# Firebase Hosting doesn't has firewall?

Tags: firebase, security, firewall, firebase-hosting, penetration-testing

Having one of application hosted on Firebase with some additional services there (Cloud Firestore, Cloud Storage for Firebase, Cloud Functions for Firebase) decided to make some security scanning. One of the tools https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ shows me that there's no firewall for it, is it possible? It has reverse proxy & Fastly's CDN, but would be a firewall missing for apps hosted on Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase hosting resources access is unfortunately not restricted by any means, check out the question below?

[Can Firebase restrict access to resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources)

However, There are things you can do in the regard of security:

1. Use Cloud functions to render dynamic resources and microservices

   - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions
2. Use Firestore rules to secure the data access
3. Use Firebase authentication to make sure that only authenticated users can do certain actions

Even though, we all hope for that firewall option to be added.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links. Hope so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting does not have a firewall feature.  If you publish content to it, that will be accessible from anywhere there is an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I think filtering traffic is something which could be added. Especially, if the Firebase ecosystem delivers such awesome experience in my opinion something like that is a very basic functionality of nowaday's hosting (sometimes paid a little bit extra).

Comment: You are always free to file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support