# Web only for authenticated users Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I am developing an HTML webpage using **Firebase**, my working tree is:

- `css`: folder with CSS style files
- `js`: folder with Javascript files
- `login.html`: logging in page
- `signup.html`: signing up page
- `app.html`: main application page

I would like to restrict the **`app.html` access only for logged users**. I have implemented in Javascript some scripts to authenticate users via email and password using the `login.html` and `signup.html` pages. For the project, I use the hosting tool that offers Firebase. However, I'm not sure whether I need to apply this capability with the hosting tools or the real time database or other. Maybe the solution is to upload my web as a real time database resource and then, control the access to some paths modifying the `database.rules.json` file, but I don't know how to implement it.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All content on Firebase Hosting is publicly available. There is no way to restrict access to your HTML or JavaScript or any of the other resources you host on Firebase Hosting.

Also see:

- [Can Firebase hosting restrict access to resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources)

As one of the answers there says, you **can** control access with Cloud Functions, but at that point it's not a static resource anymore.

It's pretty common indeed to leave the resources on Hosting unprotected, and then restrict access to the data that you show in the page, which may be loaded from one of Firebase's databases. In that case you can control access to the data with the security rules, which are fully documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). If you're using Firestore, there's also a [codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-rules) making it easier to get started.